# Command 'command' not found in python subprocess

Tags: debian, python, python3

Using the command `command` in the following python script is not successful:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["command", "-v", "yes"])
```

and results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "command_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.run(["command", "-v", "yes"])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 383, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'command'
```

In the shell (zsh) this is working as expected:

```
$ command -v yes         
/usr/bin/yes
```

How can I use `command` in a python subprocess? Do I have to install some additional packages?

### Environment:

Debian 9 (stretch) with Python 3.5.3 and zsh 5.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`command` is a shell builtin so not an own object in the file system.

See `man bash`/`man zsh` or `help command`.

```
$ python3 -c 'import subprocess ; subprocess.run(["bash","-c","command -v yes"])'
/usr/bin/yes
```

May be a solution (I have no `zsh` installed, so my example uses `bash` instead).

Comment: This is working, thanks. Additionally I found the `shell` flag for the run command `subprocess.run(["command -v yes"], shell=True)` which also solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.5, you don't need to use `command -v` to get the path of an executable. There's [`shutil.which()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html#shutil.which) (available from 3.3, I think).

```
import shutil
yes_path = shutil.which('yes')
```

Example:

```
$ python3 -c 'import shutil; print(shutil.which("yes"))'
/usr/bin/yes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['command', executable='/bin/bash',shell=True])
```

Comment: Hello Nisha. To make this a good answer, rather than just providing code it would be help to explain (to future readers, even if not to the OP) why this would resolve the issue described. You don't need excruciating detail; just a sentence might be sufficient. (I would guess the downvote is because either it doesn't address the issue as described, or there's nothing describing why this answer should be useful.)

Comment: Shell = True does really stops the error, but just fix the `["command", "-v", ....]`, executable=......)